# MSTest Visual Studio 2012 and AppDomain

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mstest

I have noticed that the MSTest is launching assemblies tests in separate AppDomain. 
Are we able to configure MSTest to avoid creating new AppDomain for each test assembly?

Answer (score 1):

You can run it with /noisolation - "Run tests within the MSTest.exe process. This choice improves test run speed but increases risk to the MSTest.exe process."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx

Comment: How can we do that in Visual Studio environment?

Comment: I don't think you can do it in the UI