# Xunit run all tests in one appdomain

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, xunit

I have a solution in which I have several projects, a few of them are test projects. I have shared some testing logic among those test, mainly static properties and methods. It turns out, however, that **both resharper and VS test runners create one testing appdomain per assembly**. How can I make them **run all tests in one appdomain**? I am using **XUnit v1.9** and this needs to be **XUnit** < 2.0. I am satisfied when either Resharper test runner or VS test runner runs all tests in one appdomain.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561802/mstest-visual-studio-2012-and-appdomain

Comment: MSTest can be configured that way, I am looking for a solution for XUnit framework

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature that xunit doesn't support, as I understand it. Each assembly is run in a separate AppDomain. I'd recommend posting an issue on [xunit's GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues), but I'd also recommend removing shared state, if at all possible.